# Popup manu placed behind other items using React Native Expo Web

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-web

I have the next layout on the page:
[image]

And I'm trying to add popup menu like on youtube mobile app:[image]

but I can't place it above other elements. React Navive for web creates own stacking context for each block. So that z-index doesn't make any sense. Is there any ways how to handle that?